# listening to change event on object in backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working on with a section of a backbone application at the moment, and we are trying to keep a track of what elements are being loaded and what attributes we need to show, in our model we have something that looks like this at initialization,

`this.set('_loaded', {items: false, files: false, currentTab:"home"});`

with the app a user can click something to fire a method that would run something like this,

`this.model.set({ _loaded : {currentTab : $click.data('tab')} });`

within the view how do I listen for this change to react to it? I have tried the following,

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:_loaded.currentTab', this.switchView);
 this.listenTo(this.model.get('_loaded').currentTab, 'change', this.switchView);
```

but to no avail, what is the correct way of changing an object within a model and reacting to that change?

Answer (score 0):

[Backbone.DeepModel](https://github.com/kahwee/backbone-deep-model) was built for this purpose.  From the repo:

> Allows you to get and set nested attributes with path syntax, e.g.
>   user.type.
>
> Triggers change events for changes on nested attributes.

I put together a quick demo that shows both setting a nested attribute and listening for nested attribute changes: https://jsfiddle.net/83e4u420/

Setting nested attribute:
`this.model.set('_loaded.currentTab', currentTab);`

Listening for a nested attributes change:
`this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:_loaded.currentTab', this.switchView);`